# BFMatcher match in OpenCV throwing error

Tags: python, opencv, surf, orb

I am using SURF descriptors for image matching. I am planning to match a given image to a database of images.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create(400)

img1 = cv2.imread('box.png',0)
img2 = cv2.imread('box_in_scene.png',0)

kp1,des1 = surf.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2,des2 = surf.detectAndCompute(img2,None)


bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L1,crossCheck=True)
#I am planning to add more descriptors
bf.add(des1)

bf.train()

#This is my test descriptor
bf.match(des2)
```

The issue is with `bf.match` is that I am getting the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == src2.type() && src1.cols == src2.cols && (type == CV_32F || type == CV_8U)) in batchDistance, file /build/opencv/src/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/src/stat.cpp, line 3749
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image_match4.py", line 16, in <module>
    bf.match(des2)
cv2.error: /build/opencv/src/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/src/stat.cpp:3749: error: (-215) type == src2.type() && src1.cols == src2.cols && (type == CV_32F || type == CV_8U) in function batchDistance
```

The error is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224846/opencv-bfmatcher-match-always-return-error) post. The explanation given is incomplete and inadequate.I want to know how to resolve this issue. I have used ORB descriptors as well with BFMatcher having `NORM_HAMMING` distance. The error resurfaces.
Any help will be appreciated.

The two images that I have used for this are:

[image: box.png]

box.png

[image: box_in_scene.png]

box_in_scene.png

I am using Python 3.5.2 and OpenCV 3.1.x in linux.

Comment: So `.detectAndCompute`  appears from OpenCV 3x and up?  I'm using 2.4 and it says `module object not found`...

Comment: It depends on the opencv version . Follow either 2.4 or 3.x.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**To search between descriptors of two images** use:

```
img1 = cv2.imread('box.png',0)
img2 = cv2.imread('box_in_scene.png',0)

kp1,des1 = surf.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2,des2 = surf.detectAndCompute(img2,None)


bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L1,crossCheck=False)
matches = bf.match(des1,des2)
```

**To search among multiple images**

The `add` method is used to add descriptor of multiple test images. Once, all descriptors are indexed, you run `train` method to build an underlying Data Structure(example: KdTree which will be used for searching in case of FlannBasedMatcher). You can then run `match` to find if which test image is a closer match to which query image. You can check [K-d_tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) and see how it can be used to search for multidimensional vectors(Surf gives 64-dimensional vector).

**Note:-** BruteForceMatcher, as name implies, has no internal search optimizing data structure and thus has empty train method.

**Code Sample for Multiple Image search**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create(400)

# Read Images
train = cv2.imread('box.png',0)
test = cv2.imread('box_in_scene.png',0)

# Find Descriptors    
kp1,trainDes1 = surf.detectAndCompute(train, None)
kp2,testDes2  = surf.detectAndCompute(test, None)

# Create BFMatcher and add cluster of training images. One for now.
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L1,crossCheck=False) # crossCheck not supported by BFMatcher
clusters = np.array([trainDes1])
bf.add(clusters)

# Train: Does nothing for BruteForceMatcher though.
bf.train()

matches = bf.match(testDes2)
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)

# Since, we have index of only one training image, 
# all matches will have imgIdx set to 0.
for i in range(len(matches)):
    print matches[i].imgIdx
```

For DMatch output of bf.match, see [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#dmatch).

See full example for this here: [Opencv3.0 docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html).

**Other Info**

OS: Mac.
Python: 2.7.10.
Opencv: 3.0.0-dev [If remember correctly, installed using brew].

Comment: I am using it for multiple images. The above code is the simplest version. The example code you have given works fine for two images. I want to compare descriptor of one image to a list of descriptor of multiple images. The problem happens there.

Comment: Sorry, i missed that. Give me sometime to see the issue.

Comment: I think I am asking this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37731908/opencv2-batchdistance-error-215-when-looping-through-images-while-individual-co?rq=1

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same error. Everything seems fine. By the way, BruteForceMatcher is not really happening, as it does no training. http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#descriptormatcher-train

Comment: I also tried FlannMatcher(since my project used FlannMatcher/C++), but faced this opencv bug: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5667

Comment: I have tried FlannMatcher too - its just a mess with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125292/discussion-between-saurabheights-and-motiur).

Comment: I think it still has the same issues when descriptors of multiple images are added as training set.

Answer (score 6):

I found I was getting the same error.  Took a while to figure out - some of my images were somewhat featureless, therefore no keypoints were found, and `detectAndCompute` returned `None` for the descriptors.  Might be worth checking the list of descriptors for `None` elements prior to passing to `BFMatcher.add()`.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the same error. But in my case it was because I was using SIFT with `cv2.NORM_HAMMING` metric in `cv2.BFMatcher_create`. Changing the metric to `cv2.NORM_L1` solved the issue.

Citing docs for [BFMatcher](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#bfmatcher-bfmatcher):

> `normType` – One of `NORM_L1`, `NORM_L2`, `NORM_HAMMING`, `NORM_HAMMING2`. `L1`
>   and `L2` norms are preferable choices for SIFT and SURF descriptors,
>   `NORM_HAMMING` should be used with ORB, BRISK and BRIEF, `NORM_HAMMING2`
>   should be used with ORB when `WTA_K==3` or `4` (see `ORB::ORB` constructor
>   description).

Answer (score 6):

Edit: Versions used Python 3.6, OpenCV 3.4.1

I struggled a lot while preparing a program that uses **SIFT** or **ORB** depending on user's choice. Finally, i could find correct parameters for **BFMatcher** for **SIFT** and **ORB**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# ask user whether to use SIFT or ORB
detect_by = input("sift or orb")
```

1. Creating matcher object

   ```
   if detect_by == "sift":
       matcher = cv2.BFMatcher(normType=cv2.NORM_L2, crossCheck=False)

   elif detect_by is "orb":
       matcher = cv2.BFMatcher(normType=cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=False)
   ```
2. While capturing and processing frames

   ```
   while there_is_frame_to_process:
       if detect_by is "sift":
           matches = matcher.knnMatch(np.asarray(gray_des, np.float32), np.asarray(target_des, np.float32), k=2)

       elif detect_by is "orb":
           matches = matcher.knnMatch(np.asarray(gray_des, np.uint8), np.asarray(target_des, np.uint8), k=2)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case using ORB, the issue was it could not find the features of the frame and checking if its empty did it.

```
qImageKeypoints, qImageDescriptors = orb.detectAndCompute(query_img_bw, None)
trainKeypoints, trainDescriptors = orb.detectAndCompute(train_img_bw, None)

if trainDescriptors is None:
    return False
else:
    # check some matching of the two images
    matcher = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING,crossCheck=False)
    matches = matcher.match(qImageDescriptors, trainDescriptors)
```