# OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (type == src2.type() && src1.cols == src2.cols && (type == 5 || type == 0)) in cv::batchDistance,

Tags: python, opencv, sift

What is this?
Can anyone tell me?
Please??

```
# create BFMatcher object
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING,crossCheck=False)

# Match descriptors.
matches = bf.match(des1,des2)

# Sort them in the order of their distance.
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)

# Draw first 10 matches.
img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches[:10],None, flags=2)
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BFMatcher match in OpenCV throwing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940766/bfmatcher-match-in-opencv-throwing-error)

Comment: i have searched it but there is nothing for help.

Comment: It says `des1` and `des2` must be the same type and size, and the type must either be `CV8U` or `CV32F`. Apparently that is not the case, but we can't tell because we can't see where they are defined.